# z3 - get domain of a function

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I have to retrieve the codomain of a function using Z3 and python. Is that possible?
Specifically I may have an expression like: f(var) = (var + 1) << 1, and I want to find out the range of the values the expression may assume.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the domain or range?

Comment: The domain of a function is by definition the range of values such a function may assume.

Comment: A function's [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) is the set of values it can accept as input. A function's [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)) is the set of  values the function may assume.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was implying the codomain. I'm looking for the codomain.

Comment: I corrected the question, thanks